# Usb mic isn't working in an Ubuntu 14.04.3 live session

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

**Issue:**

Recently, I created a bootable, persistent usb with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. When I boot into a live session, (try Ubuntu feature) my usb mic (blue snowball) doesn't work. I can't get any sound input for my applications. (Teamspeak3 and Skype)

The mic works, it isn't muted, it's getting full power and it shows up on the system settings under sound input devices. It also shows up on the PulseAudio volume control configuration tab, but it doesn't register as an input device.

[image: Input devices in sound settings]

[image: PulseAudio volume control input devices]

**What I've tried:**

- Unmutting the front mic in the alsamixer.
- Starting a test call, then selecting it as the input method from the "recording" tab on the PulseAudio volume control. (the mic doesn't show up as an option)

**Ideas?**

- Do I need to update something?
- Can I download something?
- Do I need to edit something?